# Creating perpendicular lines on line using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, line, expression, perpendicular

In QGIS I want to create perpendicular Lines on another Line (River). The Lines should be created on points on the Line and should have a length of 40 Meters. I want to create the red lines in the picture below (for the complete River).

[image: This is what I mean]

Comment: Is this a display issue, or do you need the line geometry?

Comment: I need the geometry.

Comment: The points are distributed on the line with a constant distance? Then I suggest you use GRASS GIS plug-in ''v.transects" , https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/addons/v.transects.html

Comment: Updated my answer to create geometries

Comment: @MarcM: v.transects is not available in QGIS, at least not in my installation QGIS 3.16.0  with GRASS 7.8.4. on Win10. So it can't be done from QGIS

Comment: @babel thanks for the heads up, I was not aware. Then I suggest your solution which is short and effective!

Comment: @MarcM Didn't konw about this GRASS-function, so great to learn about it. It involves using a standalone GRASS installation - so it depends if that is an option. However strange that v.transects is not included in the GRASS functions available from QGIS. Should be implemented

Comment: Do points exist already or did you add them to explain your problem?

Comment: 1) Lengthen your starting line in two directions by 50 m with "Transect"; 2) Create new points after 100 m; 3) PointstoPath; 4) Blown up; 5) Rotate by 90 degrees; 6) Buffer on the line of p.1 - 40 m; 7) Cropping by buffer p.6 - p.5...

Comment: @Cyril Mikhalchenko: interesting approach. Maybe you should add it as an answer and elaborate a bit more on the different steps involved

Comment: I believe the correct answer is the one by Cyril. However, in QGIS 3.18.2 there is the "transect" tool that does what you are looking for. No need for exploding lines and rotating them. Just 1. draw river center line 2. "points along geometry" --> draw points at wanted distance 3. "points to path" (order expression "distance") --> connect created points 4. "transects" --> select desired length 5. "clip" (Input layer = transects, overlay layer = river polygon)

Answer (score 21):

Edited answer: My first solution (see below) was for visualisation purposes only. But as you mentioned afterwards, you need the actual geometry. So this here is how to do it:

Go to `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Create points along input lines` to create points on the line in a set distance - as I can see in your screenshot, the points should have a distance of 100 meters along the line, so set the distance to 100. This creates a new pointslayer `interpolated points` with an attribute `angle` that you can use to create perpendicular lines.

As you need it as an actual geometry, use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Gemoetry by expression` and set the layer `interpolated points` as input, geometry type as line and introduce the following expression

```
extend(
   make_line(
      $geometry,
       project (
          $geometry, 
          40, 
          radians("angle"-90))
        ),
   40,
   0
)
```

This will add an additional lines layer with the perpendicular lines:

[image]

This here is the first solution that does not create new geometries, but is good for visualisation purposes:

Add an additional symbol layer to your line and define it as simple marker, selecting the symbol and size as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

In this example, I have created a marker on every vertex. If you need a marker in a regular distance along the line, just make the settings accordingly as shown in the second screenshot (the settings in the red box; the arrow shows where to check for the first solution, every vertex):

[image]

Comment: I think he needs the geometry, not the visuals

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed Answer and for your Time! I am sorry that my question was a little bit missleading, I am not pretty good in English. I should have just written to you in German :)

Comment: At least my german screenshots were not a probem dor you. Consider accepting this answer if it was useful

Comment: Hi where is the algorithm 'Create points along input lines'?

Answer (score 10):

There are many ways to solve your problem and one of them is the next:

Input data: 1) river_line layer 2) interpolated points after 100 m, see figure below

[image]

Figure 1

Action 1 - launch the geo tool "Points along geometry" with a point offset of 50 m as shown in the figure below

[image]

Figure 2

The result is shown in the figure below

[image]
Figure 3

Action 2, 3 - launch the "PointToPath" geo tool see the figure below

[image]

Figure 4

then run the geo tool "ExplodeLines" see the figure below

[image]

Figure 5

Action 4 run the geo tool "Rotate" see the picture below

[image]

Figure 6

Rezult see the picture below

[image]

Figure 7

Action 5 start geo tool "Buffer" on "river_line" layer with distance of 40 m
see illustration below

[image]

Figure 8

Rezult in the figure below

[image]

Figure 9

Action 6 Cut perpendicular lines with the buffer

The result is shown in the figure below

[image]

Figure 10

See the figure below for the intermediate result.

[image]

Figure 11

Further, in order to close the beginning and the end, you need to lengthen the line in both directions, leave only the outermost segments, turn them 90 degrees, cut and add to the result see Figure 11.

Good luck in knowing about geodata processing :-)....

If necessary, ask clarifying questions on the subject of your question, I hope that I can clarify them...

Comment: amazing pure QGIS method. I was trying to find a way to do this because SAGA has been dropped from latest installations and I used to use "Cross Profiles".. thank you!

Comment: I'm glad this method has helped you and others.....

Answer (score 5):

I first used the geotool "Points along geometry" first and then with the points with the geo tool geometry by expresion I selected the new point layer that I created and I used the next expression:

`make_line(project(make_point($x,$y),50,radians("angle"+90)),project(make_point($x,$y),50,radians("angle"-90)))`

I put 50 as half of the distance of the perpendicular lines, If you need a different distance you have to change that value.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of years later, but the function Vector Geometry --> Transects does just that at the points. In my case, I had the points, but needed the azimuth perpendicular to the line that joined them. So, I did points-to-path and then Tansects.