# Extract point data from buffered polygon layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have this polygon layer, which contains dissolved buffers that were originally created around separate points. I want to extract the points (which lie at the center of each circle) from the layer. So I need to undo the dissolving of the buffers and then find the point which lies at the centre of each circle. How do I do this in QGIS?

This is what the polygon layer currently looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try buffering with a negative distance, then find the centroids.

Or:

1. Points along geometry to create ~two points on the border of each buffer circle
2. Geometry by expression to create lines at each point location perpendicular to the circle segment. See [Perpendicular lines on line using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380361/perpendicular-lines-on-line-using-qgis)
   `extend(make_line($geometry, project ($geometry, 40, radians("angle"-90))        ), 600,   0 )`
   Adjust the lengths.
3. Line intersections to get one or multiple points at each intersection.

[image]

You can of course create the point layer manually using snapping and place two points per circle.

Comment: Thank you! It worked by using step 1 & 2 and then manually making the point layer with snapping!