# Extract central part of automatically created perpendicular lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, extract, qgis-expression, perpendicular

I have a set of lines (roadways) on layer A and a set of (mainly) parallel lines (sidewalks) on layer B. I want to create perpendicular lines at a given distance that extend from the layer A center line to the closest layer B line on both sides.

My approach so far was the following:

1. Use **Points along geometry** tool to create points along the layer A center line (example distance: 10 meters)
2. Use **Geometry by expression** tool with the following expression ([based on this GIS SE answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/380362/52808)) to create the perpendicular lines with a useful initial length, using the *"angle"* attribute created for the points along layer A geometries:

```
extend(
  make_line(
    $geometry,
    project(
      $geometry, 
      25, 
      radians("angle" - 90)
    )
  ),
  25,
  0
)
```

3. Use **Split with lines tool** to split the created perpendicular lines with the layer B lines.

The intermediate result then looks like this:

[image: Perpendicular lines, intermediate result]

A rough approach now is to just extract all the sections of the perpendicular lines that intersect the layer A center line. However, there are a few problems close to intersections where the perpendicular lines intersect the section of the center line they are based on and additionally one ore more other layer A lines. Also, the **Split with lines** tool does not cut at all sections as desired when there are more than two intersections with the "parallel" layer B lines. See screenshot where e.g. the marked line has not been cut as desired.

[image: Problematic parts of the perpendicular lines]

I am now looking for a solution (based on QGIS expressions) to initially create the perpendicular lines not with a given (fix) length and cut the undesired parts afterwards, but to extend the lines only as far as needed, which is to the closest layer B lines on each side of the center line.

I have experimented with `closest_point()` and `overlay_touches()` a bit, but I did not find a working solution yet.

Comment: Have you tried 'Snap geometries to layer'?

Comment: No, not yet. You think this might work? I need to snap each point to two different lines then and I don't see how this might work. I actually had the same problem with `closest_point()`.

Comment: I think so but as I don't have your data I'm not 100% sure. Try it, if it doesn't work, provide a sample of your datasets and I can try alternative solutions.