Splitting polygon based on river reaches line layer when perpendicular division returns bad results
I am trying to clip a valley floor polygon into reaches, and wondering if there is a automated method, or if I'm stuck hand drawing the splits.
I have a polygon layer representing the valley floor, and river reaches line layer.  As you would expect, the river is not a valley centerline, and reach breaks may or may not be in areas where the river is parallel to the valley floor .  Is there a method to automate dividing the valley based on which line is closest? I don't necesssarily need each "Valley Reach" to be hydrologically correct, but something that doesn't end up running up the valley.

Here, it would be okay for the division between features 7 and 8 to be more or less perpendicular to the line, but the division between 8 and 9 should be more or less across the valley rather than up and down it like a perpendicular cut would make.
Looking for a solution that could be implemented in QGIS or R using sf/terra.  Wondering if there is an approach that would be along the lines of:
rasterize the polygon >>
categorize the raster cells based on distance to nearest line >>
polygonize the resulting raster

The only technique that works for me is triangulation of densities polygon. Extract edges of TIN and keep only closest to reach end points. You'll need to move them to points, extend and clip

Densified polygon

@FelixIP which tool do you use to triangulate densified polygon?

I work in arcgis, it is called create TIN,, triangular irregular network. Can be done in pure python. Edges of TIN that intersect stream go from bank to bank.

I can post pictures, explaining workflow, if it helps

Create points where the river reaches meet, create a line connecting the points, (this generalizes the river reaches path), then create lines perpendicular to that line?  Perhaps such tools as extracting specific vertices, connect points plugin, and creating perpendicular lines as shown in , https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380361/creating-perpendicular-lines-on-line-using-qgis

not sure what dataset you are using to do this, but you may want to look into the idea of using a flow direction grid? Not sure of exactly what you are trying accomplish...but if you're trying to find which areas flow into which reach this would help. If you look at the National Hydrography Dataset V2 Plus this is what is done in what is they're idea of catchments.

@FelixIP I think I understand what you're doing, but if I don't include the endpoints when I calc the TIN, I ended up with divisions that are close to, but don't necessarily cross my endpoints. If I do include them, I end up with many lines originating from each endpoint, leaving a problem in selecting the nearest (also the nearest only goes from center to one side of the valley).  Can you share your method to overcome this?



Create a grid covering the extent of your polygon layer. I use a hexagon grid.

Make sure your river layer have some unique id for each river feature. Join this to each grid polygon to add a column to the grid layer with the nearest river.

Dissolve by the joined id

Intersect your river lines with the dissolved layer




This effectively results in reach breaks that extend across the valley.  Generally not straight, but this isn't a problem for my application. sf/R workflow: grid= st_sf(st_make_grid(polys, 100, square = F))[polys,] grid=grid|> mutate(nearest.reach = st_nearest_feature(grid, reaches))|>group_by(nearest.reach)|>summarize()|>st_cast()

I use this workflow for mass production of cross-sections over flood plain, because a) one can safely assume that dense TIN edge is a shortest distance between flood banks and b) banks better represent general flood flow direction, than twisty talweg line (stream) inside it.
See if this IS what you need.
INPUTS:

Move sections to chainage points:

Extend sections:

Clip extended section and find relevant remaining bits:

I do other things after, but at this stage you can split flood plain into multiple bits:


Thank you @FelixIP do you have a tool or method to snap the sections to the chainage points, or is this a by hand step?

It is a tiny arcpy script.

So you are preserving the line angle relative to the coordinate system?

Yes, it is a parallel shift of coordinates, no rotation.  Easy in arcgis, provided xy tuple moves any shape centroid to this coordinates
